# Bubbling primer

Tags: painting

We decided to finally paint our rental and after spackling, sanding, and applying primer, I found bubbles. We live in a high moisture and humidity area, so there were places that had cracked and peeled before...hence the reason for painting. I scraped the bubbles last night and by morning, the edges peeled back. As not to have cracks/peeling again, I started peeling away the primer. The primer has a good hold on what looks to be at least 2 layers of paint. The coating I’m left with is sort of glossy, smooth, and looks to be the bottom layer on the drywall. Whatever it is was not sanded prior to being painted. Annoyed, I peeled over half of what we just did. I was just wondering what the best solution is. This is only the first room and I’m assuming that all the walls will produce the same issue. Please help!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you add a picture of one of the bubbles, and the result of peeling? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: you should try different primers; some grab onto milk/oil/old paint better than others.